# mysqldump has structure but no data, only when run from cron

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I have a script with a `mysqldump` command that looks like this:

```bash
 mysqldump ${mysql_auth_args} \
        --force \
        --single-transaction \
        --quick \
        --compact \
        --extended-insert \
        --order-by-primary
```

I'm seeing the strangest behavior, and only on one machine: when I run the script directly, it works as expected. When it runs from cron though, the resulting file only has CREATE statements and no INSERTS

I've used this command to try to simulate the environment it runs in under cron and the output *does* contain data:

```bash
env -i "$(cat /etc/crontab | grep -v '#' | grep -v '^$' | grep -v /etc/cron)" /etc/cron.daily/restic-backup
```

On other seemingly identical VMs, this issue doesn't happen. Admittedly, this system is pretty dated:

```
$ mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.58, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

What factors could possibly be causing mysqldump to behave as if `--no-data` were passed, but only when run by cron?

Comment: On my system, `/etc/crontab` isn't even readable for mere users so I don't know what that was about (apart from winning a [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) award ;)), but if `restic-backup` is a shell script, maybe add a `set -x` and some logging to it to debug what it's really doing?

Comment: That little incantation is to be run from under `root`, I picked it up somewhere on the interwebs a while back as a way to approximate the env cron runs things under. restic-backup is a shell script that doesn't appear to be producing any errors. `mysqldump` _works_ and generates schema in the cases it's missing data

Comment: can you remove new lines from script of backup & write whole command without any new lines or break, only space should use for separator